# Visual Studio 2022, взять в скобки/кавычки выделенную часть

Tags: visual-studio, форматирование

Продолжаю искать функционал и настройки для Visual Studio 2022.

В Visual Studio Code был очень удобен функционал при выделение области и следом нажав на левую скобку или кавычку, получал выделенную область в нужных мне выделителях. Вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Visual Studio такое поведение не предусмотрено из коробки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где и какую настройку искать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встроенная возможность в VS есть только для C++ ([Visual Studio - Is there a shortcut to insert parentheses around a selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226014/visual-studio-is-there-a-shortcut-to-insert-parentheses-around-a-selection)), для C#/F# почему-то не добавили (на VS2022 проверил, опции нет).

Для VS2019 есть расширение [Selection Wrapper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EricMartineau.sw111) ([Highlight/Select word and put brackets or " around it VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904744/highlight-select-word-and-put-brackets-or-around-it-vs2019)), но версии для VS2022 у разработчика нет.

И на Visual Studio MarketPlace по поиску нашел такое расширение [Auto Surround](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.AutoSurround). Протестировал на VS2022, работает вроде так же, как и оригинальный функционал в VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку я отношусь немного скептически к решениям третьих сторон. Решил воспользоваться возможностями сниппетов в Visual Studio.

Решение подсмотрел в [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2769697/10562663) пользователь [Igor Zevaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129404/igor-zevaka)

Суть: создать сниппет в пользовательской директории.

Оригинальный сниппет автора

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>braces</Title>
      <Shortcut>braces</Shortcut>
      <Description>Code snippet to surround a block of code with braces</Description>
      <Author>Igor Zevaka</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[{
        $selected$ $end$
     }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Я переделал только вот эту часть

```xml
<Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[($selected$$end$)]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
```

Убрал переводы строк и подставил свои скобки. Так можно для каждого выделителя указать.

Теперь <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -> `My Code Snippets` -> `braces`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Движений, конечно больше, но как временное решение пойдет

Comment: Пока искал ответ, пробовал подобный вариант, но мне показалось не очень удобным: слишком много действий для постоянного применения, быстрее вручную набрать. Исходный код Auto Surround кстати несложный [AutoSurroundCommandHandler.cs](https://github.com/reduckted/AutoSurround/blob/master/source/AutoSurround/AutoSurroundCommandHandler.cs), при желании можно сделать fork и собрать свое расширение =) Но создать сниппет конечно гораздо быстрее, в этом плане удобно.

Comment: @alexsteeel да, это просто еще одна возможность. Больше движений, согласен полностью. Но и гибкость есть, если надо добавить еще какое то поведение: добалять пробелы, переводы строк, устанваливать в нужное положение курсор и так далее.